# Plot a histogram in matplotlib (pandas) X and Y axes specifications

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, probability

For the rolling of a six sided dice, I need to randomly simulate the event 50 times and plot a histogram of results for each number on the dice while using number of bins=6

I tried the following:

```
import random
 
test_data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
n = 50 

for i in range(n):
  result = random.randint(1, 6)
  test_data[result - 1] = test_data[result - 1] + 1

plt.hist(test_data,bins=6)
```

Is there a way to plot the numbers of the dice on the x axis and  results for each number on the dice on the y axis?

Comment: Use `seaborn.countplot` or `barplot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, I believe it is more correct to use a barchart, as the different possible results (X axis) are not frequencies. For your purpose, then, I think it is better to use a dictionary doing something like this:

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
 
test_data = {"1":0, "2":0, "3":0, "4":0, "5":0, "6":0}
n = 50 

for i in range(n):
  result = random.randint(1, 6)
  test_data[str(result)] += 1

plt.bar(test_data.keys(), test_data.values())
plt.show()
```

That should do the trick. Hope it helped!